# Attempting left join with a 'where' that only applies if the join succeeds

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I have articles, stored in an `article` table. Some articles have one or more photos, stored in a `photo` table with an `article_id` specified. Some photos are 'deactivated' (`photo.active = '0'`) and should not be retrieved.

I'm trying to get articles for the home page, and one photo for each article with one or more photos. Like so:

```
SELECT article.id, article.date, article.title, photo.filename_small 
FROM (article) 
LEFT JOIN photo ON photo.article_id=article.id 
WHERE photo.active = '1' 
GROUP BY article.id 
ORDER BY article.date desc 
LIMIT 10
```

(The "group by" is so that I don't get multiple results for articles with multiple photos. It strikes me as awkward.)

When I have the `WHERE photo.active = '1'` like that, I only get results with a photo, which defeats the purpose of making the join a left join. The where is only relevant if the join matches the article with a photo, but it's ruling out all articles without active photos. Any ideas?

(Yes, there are similar questions, but I've read a lot of them and am still struggling.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options.

1. Put it in the join clause:

   ```
   LEFT OUTER JOIN photo ON photo.article_id=article.id AND photo.active = 1
   ```
2. Explicitly allow nulls again:

   ```
   WHERE (photo.active = 1 OR photo.id IS NULL)
   ```

The second seems unnecessarily complicated though as you already have the outer join. I'd recommend the first.

Comment: Though more recent than astander's answer and not much different, I accepted this for being slightly more concise and complete. Thanks lc (& astander)!

Answer (score 3):

Try something like

```
SELECT  article.id, 
        article.date, 
        article.title, 
        photo.filename_small  
FROM    (article)  LEFT JOIN 
        photo   ON  photo.article_id=article.id  
                AND photo.active = '1'  
GROUP BY article.id  
ORDER BY article.date desc  
LIMIT 10
```