# left join with where caluse

Tags: mysql, join

I have the following tables

**discounts**

```
id    product_type    product_id    discounted_price
 1       videos           1               20
 2       videos           2               20
```

**videos**

```
id    name
 1     test-1        
 2     test-2
 3     test-3
```

**expected result**

```
 id    name    discount_product_type    discount_product_id    discount_discounted_price
  1    test-1        videos                 1                           20
  2    test-2        videos                 2                           20
  3    test-3          null                 null                        null
```

With the following query, I only get the first two rows. I know that it's because I have "and discounts.product_type='videos'", but...I don't know what to add.

```
select videos.* from 
videos left join discounts on videos.id = discounts.product_id where 
videos.id in(1,2,3) and discounts.product_type='videos'
```

Basically, I want to get rows 1,2,3 from the videos table along with rows from discounts, but **discounts.product_type** must be '**videos**'

Comment: Could it be that you need a right and not a left join?

Comment: @Mainz007 // I've tried right join, but got the same result.

Comment: Well as you told correctly: You won't get all three unless you have product_type='videos', because for three it's just not true. So only workaround would be adding: "or discounts.product_type IS NULL"
BTW: Try to work with aliases(http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp). Makes it easier to read :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite a common mistake with `OUTER JOIN`s (`LEFT JOIN` / `RIGHT JOIN`), regarding the difference between `ON` and `WHERE`.

One way to think of it is in terms of the *logical order* of the SQL statement (not necessarily the order the data is retrieved in practice, but the theoretical order the meaning is extracted); in this case:

- First, the tables are `JOIN`ed together, using their `ON` clauses, producing a set of results
- Then, the `WHERE` clause is applied, removing results where the condition doesn't match

In your query, you are first connecting up the `videos` and `discounts` tables, leaving `NULL`s where there is no `discount` that matches. Then, you are filtering that result set to those rows where `discounts.product_type='videos'` - thus removing any rows where `discounts.product_type IS NULL`.

To put it another way, the `ON` clause acts as a restriction on *which rows join*, whereas the `WHERE` clause acts as a restriction on *which rows are returned*. You want rows for other `discounts.product_type` values to be left out of the join, not left out of the query altogether.

What it boils down to is the same as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12417839/157957): move the condition to the `ON` clause, or explicitly account for `NULL` in your where clause.

Answer (score 1):

Your WHERE clause is excluding the nulls that appear on the table in the right hand side of your join. There are a couple of ways to fix this:

Move the query for the right hand side table to the JOIN clause:

```
select videos.* from 
videos left join discounts on videos.id = discounts.product_id and discounts.product_type='videos'
where videos.id in(1,2,3)
```

Or allow nulls in your WHERE clause:

```
select videos.* from 
videos left join discounts on videos.id = discounts.product_id 
where videos.id in(1,2,3) and (discounts.product_type='videos' or discounts.product_type is null)
```